# Tomcat 10 SSLHostConfig problem - protocol handler fails to start - attribute certificateFile must be defined

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, https

I have Tomcat 10.0.18 on macOS (via Homebrew).

In my `server.xml` I have

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
            maxThreads="20" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="true" defaultSSLHostConfigName="test">
     <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
     <SSLHostConfig>
         <hostName>test</hostName>
         <protocols>TLSv1.2</protocols>
         <certificateVerification>required</certificateVerification>
         <Certificate>
             <caCertificateFile>/Users/jonesn/src/egeria/master/open-metadata-resources/open-metadata-deployment/certificates/EgeriaRootCA.p12</caCertificateFile>
             <certificateFile>/Users/jonesn/src/egeria/master/open-metadata-resources/open-metadata-deployment/certificates/EgeriaServerChassis.p12</certificateFile>
             <certificateKeyPassword>egeria</certificateKeyPassword>
         </Certificate>
     </SSLHostConfig>
 </Connector>
```

However when I start & connect I see an error:

```
30-Mar-2022 09:51:08.547 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.configureUpgradeProtocol The ["https-jsse-nio2-8443"] connector has been configured to
support negotiation to [h2] via ALPN
30-Mar-2022 09:51:08.547 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio2-8443"]
30-Mar-2022 09:51:21.162 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint.shutdownExecutor The executor associated with thread pool [https-jsse-nio2-8443] has not ful
ly shutdown. Some application threads may still be running.
30-Mar-2022 09:51:21.163 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Htt
p11Nio2Protocol-8443]]
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1055)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:556)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1042)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:747)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:769)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SSLHostConfig attribute certificateFile must be defined when using an SSL connector
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint.bind(Nio2Endpoint.java:132)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1192)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1205)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:580)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:82)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1052)
                ... 11 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: SSLHostConfig attribute certificateFile must be defined when using an SSL connector
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:310)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:245)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97)
                ... 18 more
30-Mar-2022 09:51:21.164 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [13255] milliseconds
```

Yes as best I can see, I do have the value assigned.

Background -- just testing some mutual SSL config for our open-source project with some *self-signed* certs I generated. We use Spring Boot server-side, a variety of Java, Python, Go, Node etc client-side -- but for debugging/understanding I'm just trying base Tomcat, with curl/HTTPie clients.

The `.p12` files above should contain the right combination of certs/keys, but this is the area I'm exploring. I can adapt, use individual PEMs, try a chain via a directory, but this first issue seems more about the basics of defining a config and is what I'm trying to understand - being fairly new to Tomcat.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out - so will answer my own question for the benefit of future readers.

The parsing issue was down to format. I'm so used to editing other XML files such as maven, where the above format I tried is typical. tomcat was new to me, so I realised it needs to be:

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
               maxThreads="20" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="true" defaultSSLHostConfigName="test">
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig hostName="test" protocols="TLSv1.2" certificateVerification="required">
            <Certificate
                caCertificateFile="/Users/jonesn/src/egeria/master/open-metadata-resources/open-metadata-deployment/certificates/EgeriaRootCA.p12"
                certificateFile="/Users/jonesn/src/egeria/master/open-metadata-resources/open-metadata-deployment/certificates/EgeriaServerChassis.p12"
                certificateKeyPassword="egeria"
            />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

I now get other exceptions - but that is specific to the certs, something I'm debugging. I share this to answer the question specifically on why the properties could not be found.